# Matching variable value to column to retrieve value in data frame

Tags: arrays, r, match, apply

I have a data set as follows.  ds=

```
      hilldown_pod hillup_pod gnlsup_pod gnlsdown_pod      bestfit
1          NaN        NaN -2.8977432  -0.21143302         <NA>
2          NaN  0.1055303  0.1041875  -3.07497883   hillup_pod
3  -0.06537934        NaN        NaN  -0.06548488 hilldown_pod
4           NA -3.1700006 -3.0994209           NA   hillup_pod
5          NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN         <NA>
```

I'm wanting to create a new column that does something similar to a hlookup in excel. For each row, I want to search the names(ds) for the value in the "bestfit" column and retrieve the value associated with the matched column name for that record.  For example, final column would be as follows:

```
  hilldown_pod hillup_pod gnlsup_pod gnlsdown_pod      bestfit      wanted
1          NaN        NaN -2.8977432  -0.21143302         <NA>          NA
2          NaN  0.1055303  0.1041875  -3.07497883   hillup_pod  0.10553030
3  -0.06537934        NaN        NaN  -0.06548488 hilldown_pod -0.06537934
4           NA -3.1700006 -3.0994209           NA   hillup_pod -3.17000060
5          NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN         <NA>          NA
```

I've tried some apply functions and match, but i'm not getting syntax right.

```
 ds$wanted[which(ds[,(match(ds$bestfit,names(ds))]
```

Made more complicated is that these data are only a subset of columns, and I need to only match on a subset of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the row index along with the column index to extract the elements from the dataset

```
ds$wanted <- ds[-5][cbind(1:nrow(ds), match(ds$bestfit, names(ds)[-5]))]
ds$wanted
 #[1]          NA  0.10553030 -0.06537934 -3.17000060          NA
```

Comment: What if i'm only trying to match to columns 5:8 for values in bestfit?

Comment: @akaDrHouse  THen you need to change the `names(ds)[5:8]` and `ds[5:8]`

Comment: Thanks so much, that is great. I didn't realize that [value] without any comma to separate rows vs. columns defaulted to columns. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @akaDrHouse  Yes, by default, it gives the column index in data.frames, but in matrix, it should be separated by `,`

Comment: I also don't really understand what cbind is doing in your expression. Is this in place of a "which" or using apply to say do it over rows?

Comment: @akaDrHouse  The `cbind` gives a `matrix` of row index as the first column and column index as second column and it extracts the element corresponding to the index in each row of that `matrix`